# I need a php regular expression that replaces one tag with another

Tags: php, html, regex, html-manipulation

Here is what I need to be able to do:

I need to match the following tag:

```
<SPAN style="TEXT-DECORATION: underline">text sample</SPAN>
```

I need to replace the span with an html3 compliant tag, but keep the text in between.  The final tag should look like this after replacement:

```
<u>text sample</u>
```

I'm just not good with regular expressions and can't seem to come up with the answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regular expressions are not designed for tag manipulation.**

If you have any form of nesting going on, it gets messy.

However, given the very simple example provided you could perhaps do this:

```
$MyString = preg_replace
    ( '/(?si)<SPAN\s+style\s*=\s*"TEXT-DECORATION:\s*underline;?"\s*>(.*?)<\/SPAN>/'
    , '<u>$1</u>'
    , $MyString
    );
```

But this is flawed in many ways, and you are much better off using a tool designed for manipulating tags instead.

**Have a look at [DOMDocument->loadHTML()](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.dom-domdocument-loadhtml.php) and [related functions](http://phpbuilder.com/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).**

Answer (score 5):

DO NOT USE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS TO PARSE HTML

[**do not use regular expressions to parse HTML**](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4164)

*do not use regular expressions to parse HTML*

[***do not use regular expressions to parse HTML***](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html)

[do not use regular expressions to parse HTML](http://blog.mikeseth.com/index.php?/archives/1-For-the-2,295,485th-time-DO-NOT-PARSE-HTML-WITH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS.html)

[do not use regular expressions to parse HTML](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html)

do you need more clarification?

Use DomDocument::LoadFromHTML ;)

Comment: The mikeseth.com link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need several lines like this:

```
preg_replace('|<SPAN style="TEXT-DECORATION: underline">(.+?)</SPAN>|', '<u>$1</u>', $text);
preg_replace('|<SPAN style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold">(.+?)</SPAN>|', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
preg_replace('|<SPAN style="FONT-STYLE: italic">(.+?)</SPAN>|', '<i>$1</i>', $text);
```

etc. Although if there's any possibility that the tags won't *exactly* match those regular expressions (which is usually the case, except for very simple machine-generated HTML), doing this with regular expressions becomes fiendishly complicated, and you'd be better off using a parser of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

For the basic example that you've given.

```
<?php 
$string = '<SPAN style="TEXT-DECORATION: underline">text sample</SPAN>';
$pattern = '/<SPAN style=\"TEXT-DECORATION: underline\">(.+?)<\/SPAN>/';
$replacement = '<u>$1</u>'
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$string);
?>
```

will do the trick.
The pattern regex is quite easy - it's exactly what you're looking for (with quotes and '/' escaped) with a (.+?) which says to include all possible characters until the close of the SPAN tag. This assumes that you're code is consistently formatted, you could append a 'i' to the end of $pattern to make it case-insensitive.

Note that this isn't really the right way of doing it.