# ruby regex, parsing html

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to parse some returned html (from http://www.google.com/movies?near=37130 )to look for currently playing movies. The pattern I'm trying to match looks like:
`<span dir=ltr>Clash of the Titans</span>`

Of which there are several in the returned html.

I'm trying get an array of the movie titles with the following command:
`titles = listings_html.split(/(<span dir=ltr>).*(<\/span>)/)`

But I'm not getting the results I'm expecting. Can anyone see a problem with my approach or regex?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Also, this question might just be the worst formatted question ever!

Comment: The thing is, someone always bitches if I don't post every single little comment in the code. So I was just trying to avoid that.

Comment: How about posting the URL to the page you want to parse and cleaning out the pasted HTML, por favor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is considered Verey Bad generally to parse HTML with RegExs since HTML does not have regular grammar. See the list of links to explanations (some from SO) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584085/i-need-a-php-regular-expression-that-replaces-one-tag-with-another/585011#585011).

You should instead use a designated HTML library, [such as this](http://ruby-htmltools.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 4):

I didn't read the whole code you posted since it burned my eyes.

```
<span>.*</span>
```

This regex matches `<span>hello</span>` correctly, but fails at `<span>hello</span><span>there</span>` and matches the whole string. Remember that the `*` operator is greedy, so it will match the longest string possible. You can make it non-greedy by using `.*?` should make it work.

However, it's not wise to use regular expressions to parse HTML code.

1- You can't always parse HTML with regex. HTML is not regular.

2- It's very hard to write or maintain regex.

3- It's easy to break the regex by using an input like `<span><a href="</span>"></a></span>`.

Answer (score 3):

To parse HTML with Ruby, use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) or [hpricot](http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot).

Comment: I'd definitely use hpricot, it's really easy to use. There is good documentation in the readme here http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot

Comment: And I'd definitely use Nokogiri because it was able to handle malformed XML that hpricot puked on. :-) http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: @Jamie, of the two, I'd recommend Nokogiri, too.

Answer (score 2):

(it doesn't appear that the sample html you posted actually has any examples of the pattern you're trying to match.)

Alicia is correct that regex against html is generally a bad idea, and as your requirements become more complex it will break down.

That said, your example is pretty simple..

```
doc.scan(/<span dir=ltr>(.*)<\/span/) do |match|
   puts match               
end
```

As mentioned, .* is usually greedy (and I expected to have to account for that), but it appears that when used within scan, you don't get greedy behavior.  I was able to match several of these patterns in a single document.