# Php regular expression to match a div

Tags: php, regex

Foo
          
           
           Bar

```
     <div id="c">
       Bar
      </div>
```

I want find all object in id="a"
and out put is

```
 <div id="a">
   <div id="b">
    Foo
  </div>
   <div id="m">
   Bar
  </div>
 </div>
```

Geat thanks.

Comment: see html simple dom: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

SimpleHTMLDom is memory consuming solution. It may cause memory leaks.
I recommend using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).
Then you can fetch all div#a by this way:

```
$xpath->query('//div[@id = "a"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the community has responded to this before as a bad idea.  Looks to be other, better ways.  Jquery, HTML parsers, etc.

[A search on regex in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+regular+expressions)

[StackOverflow Thoughts on Regex and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875258/regular-expression-to-parse-links-from-html-code)

[PHP/HTML Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584085/i-need-a-php-regular-expression-that-replaces-one-tag-with-another)